# How do I implement other path planing algrithm for ROS global_planner?

Tags: ros, kinect, global-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to implement other path planning algrithm for ROS robot navigation,but I don't how to do it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/339540/how-do-i-implement-other-path-planing-algrithm-for-ros-global_planner?/) by [hubery524](https://answers.ros.org/users/46310/hubery524/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2019-12-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! Basically, what you have to do is to implement planner that adheres to the nav_core::BaseGlobalPlanner C++ interface in nav_core package.
Follow this tutorial, it quite nicely explains procedure of making your global planner as a plug-in to Navigation Stack:
http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Writing%20A%20Global%20Path%20Planner%20As%20Plugin%20in%20ROS

---

Originally posted by [kurshakuz](https://answers.ros.org/users/42874/kurshakuz/) with karma: 76 on 2019-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hubery524](https://answers.ros.org/users/46310/hubery524/) on 2019-12-10**:
OK,Thank you!

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2019-12-10**:
@hubery524 if you are satisfied with the answer, please mark it as "correct" by hitting the check-mark button on the left side of the answer. Thank you for keeping the forum organized!